# Bluetooth MCU for Music Application?

Tags: microcontroller, audio

I'm looking at designing my own Bluetooth Receiver essentially. Playing music from my phone to a Bluetooth receiver, to output via AUX.

I was looking at the Nordic range of MCU's for this application however I'm a bit undated with information and need a push in the right direction.

Does anyone have any recommendations on a Bluetooth MCU that would just simply receive the music and then output it.

I'm aware it's against the rules to specifically link products but was hoping someone could possibly tell me the term's of features I'd be looking for in an MCU e.g. (Bluetooth 5, DSP(?))

I appreciate any help, just hoping someone with more experience and insight than me can give me a direction to look into.

Comment: *designing my own Bluetooth Receiver* That can be interpreted in many ways. Are you designing your own chip including transceiver, bluetooth modem and microcontroller? Probably not. You probably want to build a PCB with a BT chip using an existing chip. When you buy such a chip is usually "does nothing" until **you** write a program for it. To write that program you will need to have intricate knowledge of the hardware (meaning understand how the BT chip works and how to control it). I am an experienced EE and I would not even consider doing that as it is too complicated...

Comment: ...and not needed as others have done this before already. I suggest that you get a Bluetooth **module** instead of a chip. Look on the internet for projects like BT speakers and see what they use. You would only look into using for example that Nordic IC and make the PCB yourself if you need a special form factor or features that existing modules cannot support.

Answer (score 0):

A very practical option would be ESP32, as it has Bluetooth support, plenty of RAM/CPU and a large open community of developers.

There exists ready firmware that one can use to implement Bluetooth audio receiver/transmitter. One example is [ESP32-A2DP](https://github.com/pschatzmann/ESP32-A2DP).